# Why is my Google Play Services version incorrect?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play-services, android-manifest

Today I have been updating my project and migrating from using Android.Locations API to using the Google Play LocationServices API in conjunction with a `FusedLocationProviderClient` to get location updates. I updated to the latest version of `GooglePlayServices` APIs (Base, Basement, Location, Maps, Tasks) and updated my local versions of GooglePlayServices through the SDK Manager.

When I try and use a piece of the `GooglePlayServices` API, such as the `FusedLocationProviderClient`, I get this message:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 11400000 but found 8487000. You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

But I have :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 

android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in my `AndroidManifest.xml` for my project.

What could the problem be here?

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810035/the-meta-data-tag-in-your-apps-androidmanifest-xml-does-not-have-the-right-valu

Comment: @Mohsen Unfortunately the two answers there do not solve my issue. My meta-data declaration is not nested and I just did a complete uninstall on the device and cleaned the project.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Also, Mohsen, I'm not sure why you removed the Xamarin.Android tag from this question. It could be that this issue is entirely related to Xamarin.Android and I'm missing a whole swath of the community because that tag is not there. This is built atop Xamarin.Android, and therefore Microsoft's precompiling, and could definitely be related.

Comment: You always better to mention **what IDE or platform** you are using when opening a new thread/question. Here, i assume that you are using Android Studio which is a native IDE for most folks so, i have decided to delete the [tag:Xamarin] tag which i believe it is still not related to Xamarin. Anyways. Clear enough now?! Also, please paste the whole Manifest to check if there is sth wrong and you can mention what IDE or platform you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. I'm embarrassed and not proud, but figure I should still share for the community! While I have experience with the upper levels of Android (through Xamarin), I do not have experience with somewhat obscure things like the `Resource` folder and the `AndroidManifest.xml`. In any case, I should've known that the declared value in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, `@integer/google-play-services-version`, implied that the value was declared *somewhere* within my project. Sure enough, I found that it was declared in an obscurely-located `values.xml` file.

It was indeed hard-coded in as `8487000`, and when I switched it to `11400000`, everything worked as intended. Make sure you check your entire project before making a StackOverflow post is the lesson here!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mention gms version so remove these lines from manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Just include api key for maps and other services and it should work just fine:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

This will find and add value to manifest but it won't exist if you have not created files with api keys. So you'll have to create api keys from console and store them in files in your app. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start) is guide to do that.

Also check [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) guide to learn how to setup individual google play services in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't help. I have our Google Maps API key explicitly declared in the manifest, so instead of "@string/google_maps_key," it's the actual value of the key. That has worked flawlessly for years now.

Even when I remove the first line, like you stated, I still get the error message that the application's "AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 11400000 but found 8487000." I am using Google Play Services 11.4.2 across the board; why am I getting errors?