# GooglePlayServicesIncorrectManifestValueException when checking if play services are available

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, android-manifest

We are using GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) to check for google services before showing a map. Even though the device has access to play services, the method is throwing an exception when being called. The exception is GooglePlayServicesIncorrectManifestValueException with the message:

```
“The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  
Expected 12451000 but found 4323000.  You must have the following declaration within the 
<application> element:

<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />”
```

In the manifest I’ve declared:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

If I go into the play services version, I get:

`<integer name="google_play_services_version">12451000</integer>`

Which comes from
`jetified-play-services-basement-18.1.0/res/values/values.xml`

I’ve tried most solutions in other stack overflow posts to no avail. These are all the things I’ve tried and none of them work:

- Change tag order in manifest (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810158/8575762). This has no effect, and also it makes no sense that it should have one.
- Make sure we are not providing our own hardcoded version (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63791222/8575762)
- Remove the `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` tag from the manifest.
- Update firebase libraries to latest BOM version (30.5.0)
- Remove firebase libraries completely.
- Update play services dependencies to latest version(auth, auth-api-phone, vision, wallet, location, safetynet)
- Update google services plugin to latest version (4.3.13)
- Add tools:node="replace" (also tried other manifest options like node:replace, etc) to the metadata tag & hardcode the version value

If I inspect the AndroidManifest on the built apk (debug), the value of the meta-data tag is the following:

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@ref/0x7f0b000f" />”.
```

It’s important to note that this behavior is not 100% consistent. Usually I’ll do a fresh install and the first time I launch the app the isGooglePlayServicesAvailable method returns without crashing. If I restart the app it no longer works.

This seems like a bug in the services implementation library to me, but it feels like something too simple to be failing like that.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same error. For me, the cause was the wrong 3rd-party .aar library. The library contained the unexpected @integer/google_play_services_version value in its values.xml. When I removed the .aar library dependency, my app did not crash.